# how to select transport automatically depending on schema?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wcf-client

Don't understand how to make it properly, so, decided to ask.

There is some external service. This service has two implementation - with transport security and without. So, there is two urls "http://example.com/service.asmx" and "https://example.com/service.asmx".

I have application where the user sets up (using GUI, not config) the url for connection. So, I created config with basicHttpBinding and endpoint. But the problem that if I set security="Transport" then my client doesn't work with http version of the service and vice versa.

So, what is the best approach to solve this problem? Should I analyze url schema was set by user and programmatically change binding security depending on it?

Answer (score 1):

The information that you're looking for - which binding, transport and security settings to use - is included in the service's metadata.  So if you enable service metadata on your service, then you can download the WSDL and import it.

For instance, in a C# client app, you can use `WsdlImporter.ImportAllEndpoints()` to read the endpoint configuration from your service metadata, then look for the one with the correct address:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var metadata = new MetadataSet();
using (var stream = wc.OpenRead("http://yourserver/YourService.svc?singleWsdl"))
{
    var sd = WS.ServiceDescription.Read(stream);
    metadata.MetadataSections.Add(new MetadataSection("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/", "Test", sd));
}
var importer = new WsdlImporter(metadata);
var endpoints = importer.ImportAllEndpoints();
foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
{
    Console.WriteLine(endpoint.Address.Uri);
    var client = new MyServiceClient(endpoint.Binding, endpoint.Address);
    client.Hello();
}
```

You need `System.Web.Services` and `System.ServiceModel`:

```
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using WS = System.Web.Services.Description;
```

The `endpoint.Address` in that `foreach` loop is a `Uri` that you can match against the one you're interested in.

If you're only interested in http or https, then you can also just look at the schema.

Comment: I've understood nothing at all. I have WCF-client. Users set up service url (I don't khow how this url looks like, I even don't know service's host address). Endpoint address does't set in config but in gui. Then?